# Pivot table returns empty array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to get data from pivot table(I have a third column). but it returns empty array. When I do dd() I get this

```
Collection {#323 ▼
  #items: []
}

$a = new Subject();
$authorized_users = $a->users()->get(['auth_teacher']);
```

models

Subject

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('auth_teacher')->withTimestamps();
}
```

User

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject')->withPivot('auth_teacher')->withTimestamps();
}
```

EDIT: Wrongly written column name. I change it to correctly but the string is still empty

Comment: I can't understand why you're trying to fetch a `subject_id` from a `Subject` model, can you please elaborate your question properly!

Comment: here I corrected it(it isn't subject_id it was auth_teacher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `pivot` relationship on the model.

```
$a = Subject::find(1);
foreach ($a->users as $user) {
    echo $user->pivot->auth_teacher;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

In the documentation look for "Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns"

Comment: No I'm trying to get third column from pivot table(there are keys and third custom boolean column. I need the third one). I know how to get specific users or subjects(i wrote wrong column name)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$a = new Subject();
$authorized_users = $a->users()->find(['subject_id']);
```